# How is a HTTP 200 Response?

Tags: xml, http, response

there is something I'm not able to find out. I'm playing with some services using SoapUI and Wireshark and there is something I don't understand. How is a HTTP 200 Response. I now what this status code means and on SoapUI I can see responses like this one [linebreaks edited for HTTP correctness]:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1 
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8 
Content-Length: 20
Date: Mon, 14 Dec 2015 10:02:01 GMT
```

at the RAW tab. But I see this like a parsed response. How is the xml code? Is an empty message where header indicates that it's an affirmative answer? What exactly code does the destination receive?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTTP format does not encode data using XML (and predates the existence of XML by several years).

Headers are key:value pairs separated with new lines. You aren't seeing a parsed response, you are looking at the raw headers. They are just very close to being a plain text format.

The only XML will be the HTTP response *content* (and that's only because the content-type header says the content is XML), not the HTTP response headers.

Comment: So, what destination receives is that raw response, doesn't it? Is that exactly what source sends. And response may include a body.

Comment: if I expressed my question wrongly and misused concepts, it would be nice if you corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

"Is an empty message where header indicates that it's an affirmative answer?" See the value of Content-Length: 20 (bytes). So, the message includes 20 bytes of data in the response. As answered above, what you are seeing there is the response headers, which form the HTTP response together with the response body (data).